# Search non-string elements in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I built a cell array that contains non-string elements, say, vectors containing numbers.

How can I search if a vector exits in this cell array? Since the elements are not strings, I cannot use `ismember()` function.

Concretely, if I had a cell array like

```
a = {[1 2], [2 3], [3 4], [4 5]}
```

how can I find out if `[2 3]` is in this cell array?

Comment: I do not want to use `for` to iterate the cell array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
find(ismember(cell2mat(a'),[2 3],'rows'));
```

or if you don't need the location:

```
any(ismember(cell2mat(a'),[2 3],'rows'));
```

Good luck =)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
ismember(num2str([2 3]), cellfun(@num2str, a, 'UniformOutput', false))
```